# Joining dataframe with dataframes (as lists?) or creating new variabels

Tags: r, join

My code looks like this:

```
# Dataset 1 

df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2022-12-31", "2022-09-30","2022-06-30", "2022-03-31"))


### Dataset 2 

df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2022-12-31", "2022-09-30","2022-06-30", "2022-03-31"), pe_ratio = c(22.0,22.6,22.5,28.2))

### What I want 


df3 <- data.frame(date = c("2022-12-31", "2022-09-30","2022-06-30", "2022-03-31"))
df3$pe_ratio_minus_1 <- NA
df3$pe_ratio_minus_2 <- NA
df3$pe_ratio_minus_3 <- NA
df3$pe_ratio_minus_1[1] <- df2$pe_ratio[2] 
df3$pe_ratio_minus_2[1] <- df2$pe_ratio[3]
df3$pe_ratio_minus_3[1] <- df2$pe_ratio[4]


> df3
        date pe_ratio_minus_1 pe_ratio_minus_2 pe_ratio_minus_3
1 2022-12-31             22.6             22.5             28.2
2 2022-09-30               NA               NA               NA
3 2022-06-30               NA               NA               NA
4 2022-03-31               NA               NA               NA
```

So what I want to do: For the date variable in df 1 I wanna create for each value in the df2 of pe_ratio a single variable for the previously value in df1. But the value of the actual date in df1 should not be contained.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a lot of code, most of which is irrelevant. Could you edit your question to make it a **minimal** reproducible example? You may find this link useful: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (specific for R) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There is a reproducible example. Thats because there is so much code. I structured it. I hope this helps.

Comment: We really don't need the journey, and the list of required packages is not small (`tidyverse` is a large set), not to mention I cannot find `row_to_names` within your packages, is that from `janitor`? Your question can likely be reduced to two sample datasets: `pe_ratio` and `df`. Even keeping your full code if you want, can you add the output from each of `dput(head(df))` and `dput(head(pe_ratio))`?

Comment: I appreciate that you provided code to reproduce the data, but again, emphasis is on the **minimal** in MRE. You will get much better, faster help if you remove the code and libraries that are irrelevant to answer the question and ask your specific coding question clearly. Just trying to help - good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I see it is to complex for a simple question. I rewrite my example at the moment. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: This is much simpler and clearer! Thanks! But now I have questions because your description doesn't seem to match your `df3` result. The first row makes sense, but why is the 2nd row all `NA` values, shouldn't the `2022-09-30` row have a `pe_ratio_minus_1` value of 22.5, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want, but it has fewer missing values than your result...

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "date") %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>% # make sure things are in order
  mutate(
    pe_ratio_minus_1 = lead(pe_ratio, 1),
    pe_ratio_minus_2 = lead(pe_ratio, 2),
    pe_ratio_minus_3 = lead(pe_ratio, 3)
  ) %>%
  select(-pe_ratio)
#         date pe_ratio_minus_1 pe_ratio_minus_2 pe_ratio_minus_3
# 1 2022-12-31             22.6             22.5             28.2
# 2 2022-09-30             22.5             28.2               NA
# 3 2022-06-30             28.2               NA               NA
# 4 2022-03-31               NA               NA               NA
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. This works. I noticed that I have data where the date are not all equal. Can you tell me what I have do to in this case? For example: Date in df1 is "2022-09-30" but in the df2 it is "2022-08-30". So in df1 it is ahead butt both regard to the same period.

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question illustrating that more complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[df2, on = .(date)][order(-date),
  paste0("pe_ratio_minus_", 1:3) := shift(pe_ratio, n = 1:3, type = "lead")][]
```

-output

```
        date pe_ratio pe_ratio_minus_1 pe_ratio_minus_2 pe_ratio_minus_3
1: 2022-12-31     22.0             22.6             22.5             28.2
2: 2022-09-30     22.6             22.5             28.2               NA
3: 2022-06-30     22.5             28.2               NA               NA
4: 2022-03-31     28.2               NA               NA               NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant in *base* using `outer` to place the `match`'ed dates.

```
df1[paste0("pe_ratio_minus_", 1:3)] <- 
  df2$pe_ratio[match(df1$date, df2$date)[outer(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 1:3, `+`)]]
df1
#        date pe_ratio_minus_1 pe_ratio_minus_2 pe_ratio_minus_3
#1 2022-12-31             22.6             22.5             28.2
#2 2022-09-30             22.5             28.2               NA
#3 2022-06-30             28.2               NA               NA
#4 2022-03-31               NA               NA               NA
```